# How do I find PageImagableArea for other papersizes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing, page-size

Im trying to fix a scaling issue when our application prints on other papersizes then A4. There is an existing method called GetPrintableArea, but it returns the same values regardless of what mediaSize is:

```
public Size GetPrintableArea(PageMediaSize mediaSize)
 {
  _printQueue.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.PageMediaSize = mediaSize;
  var capabilities = _printQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(_printQueue.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket);
  return new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);
 }
```

capabilities.PageImageableArea W/H is always set to the same values (761, 1090). And as far as I can see this is the selected printers imageable area for A4 (in 1/96" units). How do I get the printers PageImageableArea for other papersizes like for example A3?

Comment: I have also tried showing a printdialog and then selecting papersize there. And then use that ticket as parameter in GetPrintCapabilities(), but still I only get the PageImagableArea for A4.